# Why update function effects only to the first row?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have this table where I loop through the records on db and list them. I have update button with `updateInvoice`  onclick, and I send the id of each row to it as parameter. But unfortunetally when I try to update the rows other than first one it gets the values of first row. How can I fix this?

HTML

```
?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM FaturaHareket WHERE FaturaId = '".$faturaId."'";
$result = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);

while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)){ ?>
<form>
<tr>
<!-- EKN -->
  <td id="id" style="display:none;"><?php echo $row['Id']?></td>
  <td id="urunAciklama" class="pt-3-half" contenteditable="true"><?php echo $row['UrunAciklama']?></td>
  <td id="miktar" class="pt-3-half" contenteditable="true"><?php echo $row['Miktar']?></td>
  <td id="birimFiyati" class="pt-3-half" contenteditable="true"><?php echo $row['BirimFiyati']?></td>
  <td id="satirTutari" class="pt-3-half" contenteditable="true"><?php echo $row['SatirTutari']?></td>
  <td id="KdvOrani" class="pt-3-half" contenteditable="true"><?php echo $row['KdvOrani']?></td>
  <td>
 <span class="table-remove"><button type="button"class="btn btn-danger btn-rounded btn-sm my-0" onclick="updateInvoice('<?php echo $row['Id']?>')">Güncelle</button></span>
 </td>
</tr>
</form>
<?php  } //EoF While ?>
```

JS

```
function updateInvoice(ID){
  var faturaHareketId = ID;
  var urunAciklama = document.getElementById('birimFiyati').innerHTML;
  var miktar = parseInt(document.getElementById('miktar').innerHTML);
  var birimFiyati = document.getElementById('birimFiyati').innerHTML;
  var satirTutari = document.getElementById('satirTutari').innerHTML;
  var KdvOrani = document.getElementById('KdvOrani').innerHTML;

      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'update_backend.php',
            data: {
              faturaHareketId: faturaHareketId,
               urunAciklama: urunAciklama,
               miktar: miktar,
               birimFiyati: birimFiyati,
               satirTutari: satirTutari,
               KdvOrani: KdvOrani
                },
                success: function(response){
                    if(response == "success")
                        {
                            alert("İlgili fatura harket bilgisi güncellendi.");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            alert("Bir hata oluştu. Daha sonra tekrar deneyiniz.");
                        }
                }
            });

            }
```

Comment: you cannot have `forms` straddling table rows like you do here. The form MUST be wholly within a table-cell ( td ) or the entire table must be wholly within the form. The above html is not valid

Comment: using the same ID in the loop is also invalid - IDs MUST be unique. As it stands currently there is no way to know which element is invoked by `document.getElementById`

Comment: Your sql looks to be vulnerable to SQL injection - if that is a user supplied variable `$faturaid` then you should probably use a prepared statement ( if available for SQL Server ? )

Comment: @RamRaider I am aware of vulnerabilites, and will fix them. But right now i gott overcome this problem. Any idea how can get the realted values of each row?

Answer (score 0):

One thought and possible approach based upon my earlier comments would be to do something like this ( untested )

Essentially use a `FormData` object in the Ajax request ( the use of a form with hidden elements is not really necessary in that case ) - the form can be moved outwith the table completely and it's elements values are populated by javascript.

```
<form name='editable-details'>
    <input type='hidden' name='id' />
    <input type='hidden' name='urunAciklama' />
    <input type='hidden' name='miktar' />
    <input type='hidden' name='birimFiyati' />
    <input type='hidden' name='satirTutari' />
    <input type='hidden' name='KdvOrani' />
</form> 

<table> 
<?php

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM FaturaHareket WHERE FaturaId = '".$faturaId."'";  #   <----- sql injection possibility
    $result = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);

    while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ){ 

?>


    <tr>
    <!-- EKN -->
        <td style="display:none;"><?php echo $row['Id']?></td>
        <td data-name="urunAciklama" class="pt-3-half" contenteditable="true"><?php echo $row['UrunAciklama']?></td>
        <td data-name="miktar" class="pt-3-half" contenteditable="true"><?php echo $row['Miktar']?></td>
        <td data-name="birimFiyati" class="pt-3-half" contenteditable="true"><?php echo $row['BirimFiyati']?></td>
        <td data-name="satirTutari" class="pt-3-half" contenteditable="true"><?php echo $row['SatirTutari']?></td>
        <td data-name="KdvOrani" class="pt-3-half" contenteditable="true"><?php echo $row['KdvOrani']?></td>

        <td>
            <span class="table-remove">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-rounded btn-sm my-0" data-id='<?php echo $row['Id']?>'>Güncelle</button>
            </span>
        </td>
    </tr>


<?php  

    } //close while loop

?>
</table>
```

To process button clicks external event handlers are registered and the buttons carry the id in the form of a dataset attribute (`data-id`)

```
<script>
    Array.from( document.querySelectorAll('td > span > button.btn-danger') ).forEach( bttn=>{
        bttn.addEventListener('click',function(e){
            document.querySelector( 'input[ name="id" ][ type="hidden" ]' ).value=this.dataset.id;

            let col=this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.querySelectorAll( 'td[ contenteditable="true" ]' );
            Array.from( col ).forEach( td=>{
                let name=td.dataset.name;
                document.querySelector( 'input[ name="'+name+'" ][ type="hidden" ]' ).value=td.textContent;
            });
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'update_backend.php',
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                data:new FormData( document.forms['editable-details'] ),
                success:(r)=>{
                    alert( r=='success' ? "İlgili fatura harket bilgisi güncellendi." : "Bir hata oluştu. Daha sonra tekrar deneyiniz." )
                },
                error:(e)=>{alert(e)}
            });
        });
    })
</script>
```

A demo, fully-working but without any database interaction. The demo simply emulates the creation of a 5 row table - each cell populated with dummy data. The ID for each row is, in this case, simply the row counter variable. The buttons correctly identify this ID and create the FormData object with the `contenteditable` contents for that row

```
<?php
    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' ){
        ob_clean();
        exit( print_r( $_POST,true ) );
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title></title>
        <script src='//code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js'></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form name='editable-details'>
            <input type='hidden' name='id' />
            <input type='hidden' name='urunAciklama' />
            <input type='hidden' name='miktar' />
            <input type='hidden' name='birimFiyati' />
            <input type='hidden' name='satirTutari' />
            <input type='hidden' name='KdvOrani' />
        </form>


        <table cellspacing='10px' cellpadding='10px' border='1px'>
        <?php
            $names=['urunAciklama','miktar','birimFiyati','satirTutari','KdvOrani'];

            for( $i=0; $i < 5; $i++ ){/* assign vars with semi-random values */
                foreach( $names as $name )${$name}=sprintf('%s-%d-%d',$name,$i,mt_rand(10,100));
        ?>

        <!-- dyn content -->
        <tr>
        <!-- EKN -->
            <td style="display:none;"><?php echo $i;?></td>
            <td data-name="urunAciklama" class="pt-3-half" contenteditable="true"><?php echo $urunAciklama?></td>
            <td data-name="miktar" class="pt-3-half" contenteditable="true"><?php echo $miktar?></td>
            <td data-name="birimFiyati" class="pt-3-half" contenteditable="true"><?php echo $birimFiyati?></td>
            <td data-name="satirTutari" class="pt-3-half" contenteditable="true"><?php echo $satirTutari?></td>
            <td data-name="KdvOrani" class="pt-3-half" contenteditable="true"><?php echo $KdvOrani?></td>
            <td>
                <span class="table-remove">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-rounded btn-sm my-0" data-id='<?php echo $i;?>'>Güncelle</button>
                </span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <!-- end dyn content -->


        <?php
            }//close loop
        ?>
        </table>


        <script>
            Array.from( document.querySelectorAll('td > span > button.btn-danger') ).forEach( bttn=>{
                bttn.addEventListener('click',function(e){
                    document.querySelector( 'input[ name="id" ][ type="hidden" ]' ).value=this.dataset.id;

                    let col=this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.querySelectorAll( 'td[ contenteditable="true" ]' );
                    Array.from( col ).forEach( td=>{
                        let name=td.dataset.name;
                        document.querySelector( 'input[ name="'+name+'" ][ type="hidden" ]' ).value=td.textContent;
                    });
                    $.ajax({
                        type:'POST',
                        url:location.href,
                        processData: false,
                        contentType: false,

                        data:new FormData( document.forms['editable-details'] ),
                        success:(r)=>{
                            console.info(r);
                            alert( r=='success' ? "İlgili fatura harket bilgisi güncellendi." : "Bir hata oluştu. Daha sonra tekrar deneyiniz." )
                        },
                        error:(e)=>{alert(e)}
                    });
                });
            })
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @RamRider TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous>

Comment: I did say it was untested! Had you modified the HTML at all - thus negating that particular querySelector?